# Gerund present: "Заметив"

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I have a question about a Gerund: "Заметив" and how you as russian speakers would translate it in this context. It is derived from the verb: "заметить".

Example: ***Заметив*** как из другого вагона выходит брюнетка с мальчиком школьного возраста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could translate it as

> **Noticing** a brunette with a boy of school age leaving another car...

Or, if the action described is in the past, then

> **Having noticed** a brunette with a boy of school age leaving another car...

Comment: Правильно второй вариант.IMHO